# Multiple libcurl.4.dylib with different compatibility versions

Tags: macos, libcurl, dylib

I'm trying to run a binary executable built for **10.7** (ISCAgent in the below example) on Mac OS X **10.6.8**.

The problem with the binary is it depends on **/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib**
with compatibility version of **7.0.0**, while I only have version **6.0.0** installed:

```
$ otool -L ISCAgent 
ISCAgent:
    @executable_path/libsslserver.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libssl.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @executable_path/libcrypto.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @executable_path/libcachecom.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libxerces-c-3.1.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libicuuc.40.dylib (compatibility version 40.0.0, current version 40.0.0)
    @executable_path/libicudata.40.dylib (compatibility version 40.0.0, current version 40.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)

$ otool -L libxerces-c-3.1.dylib 
libxerces-c-3.1.dylib:
    @executable_path/libxerces-c-3.1.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    @executable_path/libicuuc.40.dylib (compatibility version 40.0.0, current version 40.0.0)
    @executable_path/libicudata.40.dylib (compatibility version 40.0.0, current version 40.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)

$ otool -L /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib 
/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.2.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 41.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
```

Currently, I've just replaced **libxerces-c-3.1.dylib** shipped with the executable with one I built myself on my Snow Leopard, and everything seems to work.

I would like to know what my other options are, however.

Particularly:

1. How can I (I'm pretty sure I can't, but still) have different versions of **libcurl.4.dylib** with different compatibility version values in the same /usr/lib directory? I'm confused a bit here -- if code contract (API) and/or ABI changes, the version number in the library file name should also be increased, shouldn't it? If, on the other hand, we have a compatibility version mechanism, what the original version number present in the file name is good for?
2. How can I affect the hard-coded library paths in a 3rd-party shared object? I have a libcurl.4.dylib (from MacPorts, compatibility version 8.0.0) residing under /opt/local/lib, but exporting a proper DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't help -- libxerces-c-3.1.dylib always picks libcurl.4.dylib from /usr/lib.